# Acessar banco de dados MDF da pasta do executável

Tags: c#

Estou tendo um problema chato de resolver, pois quero que minha aplicação acesse o arquivo do banco de dados a partir da pasta onde o executável está, pois em cada computador instalado essa pasta pode estar em um drive diferente.

Encontrei que devo usar o seguinte código para resolver o problema, onde supostamente  `|DataDirectory|` se refere à uma pasta no local do projeto, com o nome de `App_Data`, criei a pasta, coloquei o meu banco de dados lá e usei o seguinte código como string de conexão:

```
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                          AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\he_dados.mdf;
                          Integrated Security=True;
                          Connect Timeout=30;
                          User Instance=True";
```

Mas este simplesmente não funciona, e o sistema me lança a seguinte exceção:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Falha da instância.
```

Sinceramente, estou ficando cansado, tudo o que vou fazer em C# sempre tem um empecilho bobo na frente.

Comment: Você está forçando o caminho do arquivo... Não vai funcionar se o arquivo não estiver exatamente aqui: `                          AttachDbFilename=c:\folder\SampleDatabase.mdf;
`

Comment: @Ricardo Oh me desculpe, aquele era só um exemplo, editei o tópico e corrigi a coisa toda.

Comment: É isso mesmo que você fez. Coloca a exception toda na pergunta, por favor?

Comment: @Ricardo como solicitado, coloquei a mensagem da exceção na pergunta.

Comment: Muda seu Data Source para `(LocalDB)\v11.0` e vê se funciona.

Comment: @Ricardo
Na primeira tentativa deu o seguinte erro `The user instance flag is not allowed when connecting to a user instance of SQL Server. The connection will be closed.`

Assim sendo, removi o `User Instance=True`, e aí funcionou.

Agora, poderia me explicar o que aconteceu aí para ele ter funcionado?


Obrigado, você também poderia colocar uma resposta, aí fica até mais fácil para outras pessoas verem, além de ter mais uma resposta sua aceita.


Obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Registrando a solução na resposta:

```
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
                          AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\he_dados.mdf;
                          Integrated Security=True;
                          Connect Timeout=30";
```